# flutter streamcontroller not able to get data

Tags: flutter, dart

im facing the following error:

```
E/flutter (24904): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type '_AsBroadcastStream<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
E/flutter (24904): #0      new VideocallBloc.<anonymous closure> (package:video_call/bloc/videocall/videocall_bloc.dart:40:61)
E/flutter (24904): #1      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1586:10)
```

I have 2 streamcontrollers running:

```
final remoteStreamController = StreamController<dynamic>.broadcast();
  Stream<dynamic> get remoteId =>
      remoteStreamController.stream.asBroadcastStream();

       final localStreamController  = StreamController<dynamic>.broadcast();
  Stream<dynamic> get localJoined =>
      localStreamController.stream.asBroadcastStream();
```

Now when im passing informations in my `remoteStreamcontroller` i need the value of my second streamcontroller "localjoined" value but im not sure how to access it..
how can I get the value inside here?

```
remoteStreamController.sink.add({
          "engine":engine,
          "localJoined": localJoined, <- This is causing my error
          "remoteId": uid
        });
```

EDIT:

```
  userJoined: (int uid, int elapsed) {
    //final res = localJoined.last;
    //  print('++ ppppppppppp ${res}');
    print(
        '++@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ remote user $uid joined channel');

    localJoined.listen((value) {
      print(
          '++@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Value from localJoined: $value');
    });

    remoteStreamController.sink.add({"engine": engine, "localJoined": true, "remoteId": uid});
```

Comment: you cannot, `StreamController` does not provide that

Comment: oh okay, how can I receive my other value then?

Comment: make a custom `StreamController` and override `add` method for example, with that you will be able to cache last added value

Comment: could you provide me an example. Im not able to find an approach in the internet

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-stream-basics-for-beginners-eda23e44e32f

please use this article

Comment: thanks for the article, I added the listener but the print statement isnt called..

Comment: the print inside my localJoined.listen isnt getting called

Comment: ah okay, i get the idea, its because the localjoined doesnt receive any values at this time where im calling it. But my problem is that i need to read the current stream value from it at this point, since it received a value ealier. How to do that? I cant see the solution in your article propably

Answer (score 0):

Okay with the help from @Shyam Patel and @pskink I figured it out. Im caching the last value of both of my streams now so I can work with the values.

```
_repo.localJoined.listen((res) {
  print('++ stream in bloc for local: $res');
  _repo.lastLocal = res["localJoined"];
  _repo.lastRemote = res["remoteId"];
  add(UpdateVideoCall(engine: res["engine"], joined: _repo.lastLocal ?? false, remote: _repo.lastRemote ?? -1));
});

_repo.remoteId.listen((res) {
  print('++ stream in bloc for remote: $res');
  _repo.lastLocal = res["localJoined"];
  _repo.lastRemote = res["remoteId"];
  add(UpdateVideoCall(engine: res["engine"], joined: _repo.lastLocal ?? false, remote: _repo.lastRemote ?? -1));
});
```